# Token flow Authentication with facebook redirects to foursquare.com instead of the redirect_uri

Tags: foursquare

I am following the instructions on authentication with the token flow way. I have used the code provided in a sample app https://ss1.4sqi.net/scripts/apisamples-35608dc9c26343e74f5d99fc20bae6c5.js , only having added the version parameter.

When the user is redirected to foursquare to enter his/her credentials and selects to log in with facebook, after the submission he will be redirected to foursquare.com instead of the initial website.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Can't the user get redirected back to my site?

Comment: Thanks I have already set the callback url property in the app configuration and it is the same with the redirect_uri parameter. The thing is the redirection back works when i sign in with foursquare credentials, but it does not when i sign in with facebook credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your app from the [app configuration](https://foursquare.com/developers/apps) page and add a registered redirect URI for your app. Then, ensure that the redirect_uri parameter of the API request matches your redirect URI.